# PHP: What does __('Some text') do?

Tags: php, kohana-3

Reading about [Kohana templates](http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=template-site:basic_page_controller) and saw something I've never seen before:

```
$this->template->title = __('Welcome To Acme Widgets');
```

What does `__('Text')` mean? What is it? What does it do?

Comment: Weird... I downloaded Kohana and I can't find any reference to such function in the source code.

Comment: @Alvaro Maybe you downloaded version 2.x. Try and find version 3.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In Kohana (version 3) the function is defined in [system/base.php](http://github.com/kohana/core/blob/master/base.php) and is a convenience function to aid (as the other answers have mentioned) internationalization.  You provide a string (with, optionally, some placeholders to substitute values into the finished text) which is then interpreted and, if required, a translation is returned.

Contrary to assumptions in other answers, this does not use [gettext](http://php.net/gettext).

A very basic example would be (this particular string is already translated into English, Spanish and French in Kohana):

```
// 1. In your bootstrap.php somewhere below the Kohana::init line
I18n::lang('fr');

// 2. In a view
echo __("Hello, world!"); // Bonjour, monde!
```

Comment: As of 3.2, it moved to class [Kohana_I18n](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.2/master/classes/kohana/i18n.php)

Answer (score 14):

The double '__' is used for Localization in CakePHP (and possible other frameworks)

http://book.cakephp.org/view/163/Localization-in-CakePHP

Comment: The question of your comment is, What do you mean by "Localization"? :D

Comment: @ElsonSolano, No that should be pretty well known and if it's not, there are other questions here answering what it is :)

Answer (score 7):

It means someone created a function named __ (That's two underscores next to one another.)

My guess is it defined somewhere in the Kohana documentation.

Comment: He asked what does it mean. That implies to me he doesn't know it is function call. YMMV.

Comment: @Adriano I disagree, the question at least seems to suppose this is something *other* than a function. Just like $ in jQuery, this is a weird function name that may be confused as something else.

Comment: +1, not entirely useless and I agree with Tim Lytle. I'd only be upset if this was accepted over the other *finer* answers.

Answer (score 6):

It's `string gettext ( string $message )`:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php

> Returns a translated string if one is
>   found in the translation table, or the
>   submitted message if not found.

The __() is just an alias for it.  So `__("some text")` is equivalent to `gettext("some text")`

**edit:** Actually if it's two underscores than it isn't gettext().  The alias for gettext() is one underscore.

**Second edit:** It looks like __() might be another alias for gettext().  With a slightly different meaning from _().  See here: http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/9f501e31a4d4130d?pli=1

**Third and final edit:** Here's an article explaining it in more detail.  Looks like it isn't a built in function, but rather something that is commonly added in a lot of frameworks.  It is essentially an alias of gettext - it performs the same function.  However, it isn't a direct alias (I don't think).  It is implemented in and is specific to the framework.  It searches for and returns a localization or translation of the string it is given.  For more, see this blog post: http://www.eatmybusiness.com/food/2007/04/13/what-on-earth-does-a-double-underscore-then-parenthesis-mean-in-php-__/7/

Comment: Isn't that just *one* `_`, not two?

Comment: I didn't know that. But the question asks about the function "two underscores".

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Yeah, my first search turned up that article and I didn't notice that it was only one and not two.  However, on a second search it looks like it does basically the same thing.  Just implemented specific to the framework.

Comment: I suspect the framework reimplement it so you don't need to mess around with configuring gettext on top of configuring the framework.

Answer (score 6):

```
// Display a translated message
echo __('Hello, world');

// With parameter replacement
echo __('Hello, :user', array(':user' => $username));
```

See http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/I18n for details.

Comment: You can use this if the above not working echo `__('Hello, %1', $username);`