# Globalization and Localization in PHP by __() function

Tags: php, localization, globalization

I am working on globalization and localization..

I got interesting thing in a blog that is __() function, and heared many of people utlizing this function for globalization.. I read its PHP built in function but some of people using this by including some objects files .. but havn't got actual solution for this ..

I test __() function first by write this:

```
<?php
echo __("some text");
?>
```

PHP gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function __() in D:\wamp\www\test\globalization.php on line 3
```

then I used this with use_helper() function like this:

```
<?php
use_helper('I18N');
echo __("some text");
?>
```

but it gives error again ..

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function use_helper() in D:\wamp\www\test\globalization.php on line 2
```

so basically; what I need to know is .. is there any simplest way for globalization and localization in PHP? and how above __() php function works .. what i need to include in this more?

Comment: please select a correct answer

Answer (score 3):

`__()` is not a function included in PHP. PHP has the `_()` function, which is an alias for [`gettext`](http://php.net/gettext), which uses the Gettext system for localization. `__()` is a popular name for a localization helper, which a lot of frameworks use to implement their own localization function.

In other words: go with PHP's gettext functions, or roll your own.

Answer (score 2):

This is only if you are using frameworks that implement this method: Wordpress, Kohana, etc.  See [this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427907/76734)