# Echo in one line in PHP

Tags: php, echo

I want to change the original code I have,

```
echo "<p><strong>" . __('Area:', 'honegumi') . "</strong> " . number_format($productarea) . " m² (";
echo metersToFeetInches($productarea) . " ft²)" . "</p>";
```

into a single `echo` line as shown here:

```
echo "<p><strong>" . __('Area:', 'honegumi') . "</strong> " . number_format($productarea) . " m² (" . metersToFeetInches($productarea) . " ft²)" . "</p>";
```

But I'm getting some strange line breaks in this second case for **metersToFeetInches($productarea)**.

Generated HTML:

```
    24,757
<p>
<strong>Area:</strong>
2,300 m² ( ft²)
</p>
```

Output:

```
    24,757
    
    Area:
    2,300 m² ( ft²)
```

How can I solve it? Is there any documentation I could read to learn how to do it by myself in the future?

Comment: Post the generated HTML.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: It's probably a localization function. IIRC, Wordpress uses one with a similar name.

Comment: _() is an alias of gettext function @WesleyMurch

Comment: @MrinmoyGhoshal: So it is, interesting, thanks. I see `__()` is part of Kohana and CakePHP as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427204/php-what-does-some-text-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I know what's going on here, your function `metersToFeetInches` is `echo`ing a value rather than `return`ing it.

```
function metersToFeetInches() {
   echo 'OUTPUT';
}

echo 'FIRST '.metersToFeetInches().' LAST';
// Outputs: OUTPUTFIRST  LAST
```

`echo metersToFeetInches()` is actually redundant.

This is because the function runs before the string you built is actually output. Note that both examples you posted would have this problem. Change your function to `return` a value instead. Afterwards, any places where you have used it like so:

```
echo 'Something';
metersToFeetInches();
echo 'Something Else';
```

You'll have to use an `echo`:

```
echo 'Something';
echo metersToFeetInches();
echo 'Something Else';
```

Functions should pretty much always `return` a value. Lesson learned, perhaps?

---

If you are really in a bind and cannot change the function, you'll have to resort to [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php):

```
ob_start();
metersToFeetInches($productarea);
$metersToFeetInches = ob_get_clean();

echo "<p><strong>" . __('Area:', 'honegumi') . "</strong> " . number_format($productarea) . " m² (" . $metersToFeetInches . " ft²)" . "</p>";
```

...which is rather silly to have to do.

Comment: Thanks Wesley!
The problem was that the function, as you said, was echoing instead of returning.

Now works like a charm!